# chromebook screen stripes pattern under camera only

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

Wondering if anyone has ever encountered this or has some good advice. I'd appreciate. Namely, while taking a photo of my chromebook screen, I noticed that the image was not static at all as it was when looking directly at the screen. Instead I saw a dizzying pattern of alternating dark-white stripes running in one direction. The pattern runs over the entire screen and it is changing its speed and the width of the stripes, at different times when I check it again, now out of curiosity. When I filmed this in "slow mode", the pattern started to move very fast and it showed clearly alternating black and white stripes. A very hypnotic view, I have to admit. Any advice, please share. Thank you

Comment: Search for 'rolling shutter' and 'lcd vertical refresh'.

Answer (score 0):

More of an addendum to my posting. Why do I see something else on my chromebook only when using a smartphone or iPad camera for photos / video ? Even the slow mode video behaves otherwise than it should, and it actually accelerates the pattern while also better defining the stripes. And why does the pattern change ? What puzzles me, is rather this dual mode, of seeing the plain screen with the naked eye, directly looking at the chromebook screen, and these moving vertical stripes when looking through a smartphone / iPad camera. Any optics issues involved, or polarization, or is it just a sofwtare glitch ? Did others ever observe this, too ? Thank you for any advice or related stories you may want to share.